# How to change the correct answer text to green while changing the wrong answer text color to red

Tags: java, android

I have a `TextView` and a radio group with four radio buttons in a `ListView`. when user select the radio button the text color changes to green if answer is correct and if answer is wrong text color changes to red which is working perfectly but I want if answer is wrong it also changes the correct answer text to green.

```
    if (opt1.getText.toString.equals(correctans)) {
                opt1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_ans));
                iv_optA.setImageResource(R.drawable.correctans);
                iv_optB.setImageResource(R.drawable.dontknowans);
                iv_optC.setImageResource(R.drawable.dontknowans);
                iv_optD.setImageResource(R.drawable.dontknowans);


            } else {
                opt1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.wrong_ans));
                iv_optA.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrongans);
                iv_optB.setImageResource(R.drawable.dontknowans);
                iv_optC.setImageResource(R.drawable.dontknowans);
                iv_optD.setImageResource(R.drawable.dontknowans);
            }
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Do you know which view contains the correct answer?

Comment: What is the difference between `opt1` and `opt_1`? This variable names are so similar that it is easy to confuse them. I suggest you change these to something more meaningful and easily differentiated.

Comment: i have 2 text view and 4 radio buttons. question textview and answer text view. my answer is stored in answer text view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

```
    String opt_1 = opt1.getText().toString();
    if (opt_1.equals(correctans)) {
                opt1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_ans));
                iv_optA.setImageResource(R.drawable.correctans);
            } else {
                opt1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.wrong_ans));
                iv_optA.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrongans);
                if (opt_1.equals(correctans))
                    opt1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                if (opt_2.equals(correctans))
                    opt2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                if (opt_3.equals(correctans))
                    opt3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                if (opt_4.equals(correctans))
                    opt4.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
```